# Adding Python to .Net Core Docker File And Running at command line

Tags: python-3.x, .net, docker

I am attempting to add Python to a .Net Core Web API that is run via a Docker file.  I added the Run command to install Python, and I see a bunch of install information when the Docker starts.  However, if I terminal into the container, and type python3 at the command line, it isn't picked up:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install python3.10 -y

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DemoApp/DemoApp.csproj", "DemoApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DemoApp/./DemoApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DemoApp"
RUN dotnet build "./DemoApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./DemoApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DemoApp.dll"]
```

I get a python3: not found.

If I do a whereis python3.10, I get

```
python3: /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python3.9
```

So, simple question: how do I run python from the command line after the container has launched.  Or, how do I set up the Docker file so this is accomplishable?